# Curses Pad strange behivour

Tags: ruby, curses

I'm trying to create a text viewer that is wider than the screen so that I can scroll right and left. I'm using `Curses::Pad` for this. The documentation states that `Pad` can be bigger than the screen.

Please consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby2.1

require 'curses'

Curses.init_screen

pad = Curses::Pad.new Curses.lines, Curses.cols * 10

0.upto(200) do |i|
  pad.setpos(i, 0)
  pad.addstr(0.upto(600).to_a.join(","))
end

pad.refresh 0,0,0,0,Curses.lines,Curses.cols
sleep(3)
pad.refresh 0,200,0,0,Curses.lines,Curses.cols

sleep(200)
```

When the `Pad` size is bigger than the screen size, nothing is shown. When the `Pad` size is the same as the screen size, the second `refresh` fails unless `min_pad_col` is smaller than `pad`.

Cab anyone point what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: Same library, same api. Maybe some of the python folks have some insight on this.

Comment: That's not a good reason to add a completely unrelated tag. The tag python should be used if python code is involved. Otherwise you could have tagged the question with *any* language that has bindings for the `curses` library.